# How to reset setcontentview() dynamically within a program?

Tags: android, layout, background

I am trying to rotate an image on a loading page and so I have four images, each rotated 90 degrees to the right from the next and I wish to sleep then reset contentview on each one to proceed to the next. Is there any way I can do this without having to start a new intent for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `invalidate()` on your layouts if I understand your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class and calling [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) with a Runnable instance that will switch the image and the time you wish to delay the image switch.

That being said, I would make sure your design couldn't better be handled via animation or something similar.